# Is this the right way to calculate the fletcher64 checksum

Tags: c, checksum, reliability

The fletcher16 source code is given like this on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum#Fletcher-64).

```
uint16_t Fletcher16( uint8_t* data, int count )
{
   uint16_t sum1 = 0;
   uint16_t sum2 = 0;
   int index;

   for( index = 0; index < count; ++index )
   {
      sum1 = (sum1 + data[index]) % 255;
      sum2 = (sum2 + sum1) % 255;
   }

   return (sum2 << 8) | sum1;
}
```

From that example, I implemented the 64 bit version as follows.

```
unsigned long Fletcher64( unsigned int* data, int count )
{
   unsigned long sum1 = 0;
   unsigned long sum2 = 0;
   int index;

   for( index = 0; index < count; ++index )
   {
      sum1 = (sum1 + data[index]) % UINT_MAX; // UINT_MAX = 2^32
      sum2 = (sum2 + sum1) % UINT_MAX;
   }

   return (sum2 << 32) | sum1;
}
```

Is my approach correct, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The comment "UINT_MAX = 2^32" is incorrect, as UINT_MAX would be 2^32-1 for 32 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most hash algorithms take parameters of a block of memory and the number of bytes (or sometimes bits) to hash.  You have changed a byte count to a word count—a rather significant change.

Also, since you have changed the calculation size, the way `sum2` is computed has changed.  This is fine as long as you are not trying to replicate the original algorithm value-per-value, but if this is meant as a compatible optimization, then this is probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong. You will be missing 0-3 bytes of trailing data, because you're only summing up the DWORDs in the data, but might still have some bytes left, depending on the data size. I'd propose these [implementations](http://ideone.com/j4bCWA):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t fletcher64_A(const uint8_t * data, uint64_t count)
{
    // calculate how many full double words the input has
    uint64_t dwords = count / 4;
    // now calculate the flechter-64 checksum from double words
    uint64_t sum1 = 0;
    uint64_t sum2 = 0;
    const uint32_t * data32 = reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(data);
    for (uint64_t index = 0; index < dwords; ++index) 
    {
        sum1 = (sum1 + data32[index]) % UINT32_MAX;
        sum2 = (sum2 + sum1) % UINT32_MAX;
    }
    // calculate how many extra bytes, that do not fit into a double word, the input has
    uint64_t remainingBytes = count - dwords * 4;
    if (remainingBytes > 0)
    {
        // copy the excess bytes to our dummy variable. you could use memcpy here...
        uint32_t dummy = 0;
        for (uint64_t index = 0; index < remainingBytes; ++index)
        {
            reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&dummy)[index] = data[dwords * 4 + index];
        }
        // now add the dummy on top
        sum1 = (sum1 + dummy) % UINT32_MAX;
        sum2 = (sum2 + sum1) % UINT32_MAX;
    }
    // build final checksum
    return (sum2 << 32) | sum1;
}

uint64_t fletcher64_B(const uint8_t * data, uint64_t count)
{
    // calculate how many full double words the input has
    uint64_t dwords = count / 4;
    // now calculate the flechter-64 checksum from double words
    uint32_t sum1 = 0;
    uint32_t sum2 = 0;
    const uint32_t * data32 = reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(data);
    for (uint64_t index = 0; index < dwords; ++index) 
    {
        sum1 += data32[index];
        sum2 += sum1;
    }
    // calculate how many extra bytes, that do not fit into a double word, the input has
    uint64_t remainingBytes = count - dwords * 4;
    if (remainingBytes > 0)
    {
        // copy the excess bytes to our dummy variable. you could use memcpy here...
        uint32_t dummy = 0;
        for (uint64_t index = 0; index < remainingBytes; ++index)
        {
            reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&dummy)[index] = data[dwords * 4 + index];
        }
        // now add the dummy on top
        sum1 += dummy;
        sum2 += sum1;
    }
    // build final checksum
    return ((uint64_t)sum2 << 32) | sum1;
}

int main() {
    const std::string data = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789helloworld!";
    uint64_t ca = fletcher64_A(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(data.data()), data.size());
    uint64_t cb = fletcher64_B(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(data.data()), data.size());
    std::cout << "String size: " << data.size() << ", checksum a: 0x" << std::hex << ca << ", checksum b: 0x" << cb << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which take the trailing bytes into account. fletcher64_A is the naiive implementation and flechter64_B does the modulo as bescribed by Mecki. You can see that both implementations produce the same values (they do not. see edit).

EDIT #1:
This is not quite correct as Thomas Tempelmann commented. Will try to fix the algorithm at some point.
You can check when the summing in the fletcher algorithm will overflow [here](http://ideone.com/7dHDCg). This more or less matches with what the wikipedia entry says.

EDIT #2:
I've whipped up a test using a templatized version of the naiive and optimized algorithm here. Compile and run it using "g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic test.cpp && ./a.out". The takeaway is that the 32-bit version is working, but not the 16- and 64-bit versions. I'd appreciate if you find the bug and comment. @Thomas Tempelmann: The optimized version is roughly 6 times faster on my computer!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <limits>

uint64_t test_overflow(uint64_t start, uint64_t add, uint64_t check)
{
    uint64_t count = 0;
    uint64_t sum1 = start;
    uint64_t sum2 = start;
    do
    {
        sum2 += sum1 += add;
        count++;
    } while (sum1 + add < check && sum2 + (sum1 + add) < check);
    return count;
}

template <class T, class R>
T fletcherTA(const uint8_t * data, const T & count, const T & start)
{
    // calculate how many full R-words the input has
    T rwords = count / sizeof(R);
    // calculate how many extra bytes, that do not fit into an R-word, the input has
    T remainingBytes = count - rwords * sizeof(R);
    // now calculate the flechter-T checksum from R-words
    T sum1 = start & std::numeric_limits<R>::max();
    T sum2 = start >> (sizeof(R)*8);
    const R * dataR = reinterpret_cast<const R*>(data);
    while (rwords)
    {
        rwords--;
        sum1 = (sum1 + *dataR++) % std::numeric_limits<R>::max();
        sum2 = (sum2 + sum1) % std::numeric_limits<R>::max();
    }
    if (remainingBytes > 0)
    {
        // copy the excess bytes to our dummy variable. you could use memcpy here...
        R dummy = 0;
        const uint8_t * data8 = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(dataR);
        for (uint64_t index = 0; index < remainingBytes; ++index)
        {
            reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&dummy)[index] = data8[index];
        }
        // now add the dummy on top
        sum1 = (sum1 + dummy) % std::numeric_limits<R>::max();
        sum2 = (sum2 + sum1) % std::numeric_limits<R>::max();
    }
    // build final checksum
    return (sum2 << sizeof(R)*8) | sum1;
}

template <class T, class R, T overflowAfter>
T fletcherTB(const uint8_t * data, const T & count, const T & start)
{
    // calculate how many full R-words the input has
    T rwords = count / sizeof(R);
    // calculate how many extra bytes, that do not fit into an R-word, the input has
    T remainingBytes = count - rwords * sizeof(R);
    // now calculate the flechter-T checksum from R-words
    T sum1 = start & std::numeric_limits<R>::max();
    T sum2 = start >> (sizeof(R)*8);
    const R * dataR = reinterpret_cast<const R*>(data);
    while (rwords)
    {
        T tlen = ((rwords >= overflowAfter) ? overflowAfter : rwords);     
        rwords -= tlen;
        do 
        {
            sum2 += sum1 += *dataR++;
            tlen--;
        } while (tlen);
        sum1 = (sum1 & std::numeric_limits<R>::max()) + (sum1 >> (sizeof(R)*8));
        sum2 = (sum2 & std::numeric_limits<R>::max()) + (sum2 >> (sizeof(R)*8));
    }
    if (remainingBytes > 0)
    {
        // copy the excess bytes to our dummy variable. you could use memcpy here...
        R dummy = 0;
        const uint8_t * data8 = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(dataR);
        for (uint64_t index = 0; index < remainingBytes; ++index)
        {
            reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&dummy)[index] = data8[index];
        }
        // now add the dummy on top
        sum2 += sum1 += dummy;
        sum1 = (sum1 & std::numeric_limits<R>::max()) + (sum1 >> (sizeof(R)*8));
        sum2 = (sum2 & std::numeric_limits<R>::max()) + (sum2 >> (sizeof(R)*8));
    }
    // build final checksum
    return (sum2 << (sizeof(R)*8)) | sum1;
}

template <class T, class R, T overflowAfter>
void test_implementations()
{
    std::cout << "Testing " << sizeof(T)*8 << " bit implementations:" << std::endl;
    // test flechter overflow
    std::cout << "Overflow after: " << test_overflow(0, std::numeric_limits<R>::max(), std::numeric_limits<T>::max() - std::numeric_limits<R>::max()) << " rounds (start value 0)." << std::endl;
    // test fletcher checksum in both implementations with the same data
    const uint64_t dataSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // 1 * 1024 * 1 MB = 1 GB of test data
    const uint64_t blockSize = std::min(std::min(dataSize, (uint64_t)10 * 1024 * 1024), (uint64_t)(std::numeric_limits<T>::max() - std::numeric_limits<T>::max() % 4));
    const T oddBlockSize = static_cast<T>(blockSize - 1);   
    const uint64_t nrOfBlocks = dataSize / blockSize;
    std::vector<uint32_t> data(blockSize / sizeof(uint32_t));
    // initialize random number generator using current time
    std::minstd_rand prng(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
    std::cout << "Testing checksums with " << std::dec << dataSize / (1024 * 1024) << " MB of data in " << blockSize / 1024 << " kB blocks..." << std::endl;
    T ca = 0;
    T cb = 0;   
    for (uint64_t block = 0; block < nrOfBlocks; block++)
    {
        // generate random numbers
        std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), [&prng](){ return prng(); });
        // apply checksum function. make sure to use an odd value to test remaining bytes being captured
        ca = fletcherTA<T, R>(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(data.data()), oddBlockSize, ca);
        cb = fletcherTB<T, R, overflowAfter>(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(data.data()), oddBlockSize, cb);
    }
    std::cout << "Checksum A: 0x" << std::hex << ca << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Checksum B: 0x" << std::hex << cb << std::endl;
    // test speed
    const uint64_t runs = nrOfBlocks;
    std::cout << "Testing speed with " << std::dec << dataSize / (1024 * 1024) << " MB of data..." << std::endl;
    auto startA = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (uint64_t run = 0; run < runs; run++)
    {
        ca = fletcherTA<T, R>(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(data.data()), oddBlockSize, ca);
    }
    auto endA = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto startB = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (uint64_t run = 0; run < runs; run++)
    {
        cb = fletcherTB<T, R, overflowAfter>(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(data.data()), oddBlockSize, cb);
    }
    auto endB = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Checksum A: 0x" << std::hex << ca << ", took " << std::dec << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endA-startA).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Checksum B: 0x" << std::hex << cb << ", took " << std::dec << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endB-startB).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    test_implementations<uint16_t, uint8_t, 20>();
    test_implementations<uint32_t, uint16_t, 359>();
    test_implementations<uint64_t, uint32_t, 683442530>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your B version is not correct for larger amount of bytes because eventually you'll run into an overflow, and that's where you'll get it wrong. For details, see the WP article, under "Optimizations", and the limit value 360. For fletcher64, the correct limit value needs to be determined first, though. Keep in mind that UINT32_MAX is not 2^32 but 2^32-1.

Comment: You might be correct. I haven't tested it for enough data... Could you provide a correct implementation?

Comment: You'd have to use 64 bit ints for the sums and add `sumX = (sumX & UINT32_MAX) + (sumX >> 32)` (X being 1 and 2 each) in the loops. But on a modern CPU the modulo (%) code might be even faster as it can do modulo in just a few cycles and takes less than the AND and OR operations. Therefore, to get max speed, rather use the optimization with the counter up to 359 as shown in the WP article.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it seems to be correct, but make sure to test it.